# AWS Cognito - RESET_REQUIRED redirect not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, browser, amazon-cognito

Currently I'm using the default UI from cognito to authenticate my users.
When i mark them as RESET_REQUIRED The redirect to forgot_password is not working.

Here's the request and Response Header...

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Date: Tue, 05 Jun 2018 21:22:15 GMT
Expires: 0
Location: redirect:/forgotPassword?redirect_uri=https://domain.delist&response_type=code&client_id=4711&errorMessage=Password reset required for user due to security reasons.
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Server
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

Any Idea or do i miss somthing?

Answer (score 0):

I think your Location header is incorrect - try removing the "redirect:" so it is

`Location: /forgotPassword?redirect_uri=https://domain.delist&response_type=code&client_id=4711&errorMessage=Password reset required for user due to security reasons.`